# How to access stdclass json object in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

My JSON is in the form of stdclass object. How can I iterate through my JSON. My JSON is like:

```
$scope.mytest=[  array(161) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#4 (14) {
  ["arrivalTime"]=>
  string(8) "17:00:00"
  ["availableSeats"]=>
  string(2) "42"
  ["boardingPointDetails"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
      ["code"]=>
      string(4) "1631"
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "Koyambedu"
      ["time"]=>
      string(8) "09:30:00"
     } 
   ....
}];
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this look like an php object. 
you should encode it in php before sending it to your JS

```
  // PHP side:
  return json_encode(yourObject)
```

then return it to the JS and parse it

```
// JS side
$http.get(...).then(function(res){
      JSON.parse(res) 
      ...
});
```

---

You should get a JSON like this :

```
$scope.mytest = [  { 
        "0" : {
            "arrivalTime" : "17:00:00",
            "availableSeats" : "42",
            "boardingPointDetails" : [{
                    "0" : {
                        "code" : "1631",
                        "name" : "Koyambedu",
                        "time" : "09:30:00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        ....
    }
];
```

if you can access to the first element of an array : `$scope.mytest[0]`.

if you want to access to a property of an object : `yourObject["keyname"]`
example :

```
var myobject = {
    "arrivalTime" : "17:00:00",   // myobject["arrivalTime"] or myobject.arrivalTime
    "availableSeats" : "42",
    "boardingPointDetails" : [   // myobject.boardingPointDetails
         {                   // myobject.boardingPointDetails[0]
            "0" : {               // myobject.boardingPointDetails[0]["0"]
                "code" : "1631",  // myobject.boardingPointDetails[0]["0"]["code"]
                "name" : "Koyambedu",
                "time" : "09:30:00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is that possible to do with angular (without using Php).

Comment: Are you just pasting data coming from php vardump ? the data sended should not be formatted like this

Comment: this was the JSON given to me and asked to iterate through this json using angularJs..please help me..

Comment: this is not a json sorry. this a php object vardumped. i cannot to anythink with it. can you ask to make a `var_dump(json_encode(yourObject))` ?

Comment: welcome. you should get something like this  `[{
 "0": {
  "arrivalTime": "17:00:00",
  "availableSeats": "42",
  "boardingPointDetails": [{
   "0": {
    "code": "1631",
    "name": "Koyambedu",
    "time": "09:30:00"
   }

  }]
 }
 ....
}];

Comment: yes..but this is what the task assigned to me..now Im clear..I got my nested json..now I'm going to see how can I access values of nested json...thank you so much Alainlb...:)

Comment: Is that any need to save my JSON in variable...??

Comment: you have to save your initial json in the beggining as you do with `$scope.mytest=[]`. after that no you don't need to save other json expect if you want to make your life easier instead of dealing with very long path. 
for example to access to `boardingPointDetails` you have to do `$scope.mytest[0]["0"]["boardingPointDetails"][0]["0"]`. you can create a reference `var boardingPointDetails=$scope.mytest[0]["0"]["boardingPointDetails"][0]["0"]` so you can manipulate nested property easly ( this will not create another json just a pointer reference to this node )